# Adding Sample Questions to 'on topic' Page

Tags: discussion

At the suggestion of @Air, I'm posting this [answer to another question](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/great-questions-from-the-datascience-se-beta/2214?noredirect=1#comment1199_2214) here as a new question.

I'm new the DS.SE, but have been using SO.SE for years. Having just now looked in the on topic questions, I find there aren't any. This may be part of the reason there is so much trouble in distinguishing between CV.SE and DS.SE.

I do see the need for DS.SE, but there is a danger it will never get past the beta.

I'm currently too low to edit the 'on topic' page.

**Suggested questions**

1. When using Stream Insight module from Azure with 10 ms data from one process, what statistical tool should I use to best monitor a change of process - either distribution/mean?
2. I would like to produce a infographic on the 'Brexit' referendum. What public data sources might I use and how to summarise in a meaingful way, in order to visualise into a dashboard?
3. Is R or Python better for executing an ARIMA model over SPARK?
4. How does the auto scale feature of Azure work in relation to Stream Insight / blob storage and does this improve the performance of Azure ML models?

Also, there are some very good questions on the DS Area 51 site, which could be considered for addition to the DS.SE on topic questions list. (there are also some very poor questions as well, which should have never been voted up, IMHO!)

|------ Edit ------|

I've accepted this answer below, but I think it would still be great to have riches diversity of answers, so would be very happy with further answers (i.e. questions) added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be happy to make the edits. Dumb question: what is the on-topic page? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic or the questions rolling by at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/tour or something else?

I might choose somewhat different examples though. For example, questions about available data sets belong on the Open Data SE. Is R or Python better -- sounds likely to be opinion-based.

I agree with the other two, since they involve questions of statistics and the engineering of systems using them.

Comment: It is the first of your links, but the second looks like it could use some more relevant links. Different examples are good, was hoping to get some discussion going! The R vs Python, the answer is Python is better on Spark, since the SparkR libraries are not as fully functional as the Python libraries. Imho not opinion based.

Comment: The question on Brexit, was to use public data, but then visualise it, so its combining OD.SE and visualisations ...

Comment: I'll have to edit these (two Azure questions?) but will combine these with some other examples I think characterize the site.